# Google Cardboard "Game Over" screen with a designed image

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am trying to implement a game over screen for my Unity 3D based game for Google Cardboard. I have tried using the image UI component on a canvas component. The image appears just fine but the issue is that it seems to show up over the reticles. I would like to have the image perfectly fit the inside of the reticle. I am considering somehow finding out (somehow) the size of the reticle and exporting my image as a png with transparency around its graphics.

My Question:
Is there a better way to do this? If not, what are the dimensions i can use for the duplicate images (for the two reticles) to perfectly fit the Google Cardboard reticle openings.

Answer (score 0):

When using Google Cardboard (Now GVR), I think it is best to use **Quad GameObject** for Game Over screens to which you can add images and child objects like **3D Text** and collection of child quads.

The best thing about using quads and 3d text is the extent of scripting that can be done to make them dynamic as well as styling. And in your case, **Physics Raycasters** work well for the reticle to interact with those GameObjects.

You can add materials and textures to the quad and what not! I personally love quads for GameOver screens as well as a lot of other interact-able things.